# How to change menu color without affect dropdown menus

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, colors, menu

Tried so many guides on internet but can't make exactly what i want, probably because Wordpress theme is limiting my customization

I want to change the menu color, i did on normal menus but on dropdown ones i can't, every time i change the color change on every dropdown, how can i do this.

I want my website to change menu color in every post category, .category-overwatch is for get category and .menu-mais-jogos is the custom class on menu, but when i wrote the code below, change the menu and all the dropdown

What i'm doing right now is changing the custom CSS class i create on Menu, but didn't create in dropdown ones.

```
.category-overwatch .menu-mais-jogos a{
    background-color: #f79f11 !important;

}
```

how to change only the menu and not the dropdown?

Comment: perhaps by using `.category-overwatch .menu-mais-jogos:not(select) a` as a selector. But without a bigger example you probably will need someone more specialised in wordpress and possible how you structures your classes.

Comment: this selector helps on other thing i have in mind, but not on the main problem. Like, right now it's like [this](https://i.imgur.com/eG6zSwn.png), but i want this looks like [that](https://i.imgur.com/IEe4WdX.png)

The not selector doesn't changes the dropdown.
So, probably the dropdown has earned the same classes from the first one, right?. i need to make a different class to dropdown and edit on code?

Comment: Try using `a:hover` and `a:active` for that